# What is right place for placing Jersey ResourceConfig

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I have following projects :

- web,
- Rest,
- Service

Can anyone please tell me, what is the best place to keep code for `class` which `extends`  Jersey's `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.Wether` class. It should be in Web project or Rest project ?

Answer (score 0):

In my projects i keep the ResourceConfig class close to the ResourceClasses (the actual restclasses). Which should be the Rest Project in your case

I do this for the following reasons

- The ResourceConfig controls how your Resources gets loaded so i makes sense to have them near the resourceclasses
- It gives you the ability to use your ResourceConfig in your (Unit|Integration)Tests, maybe even use 2 different Configs that extend a DefaultConfig for things like Fakedatabases vs real databases in Test and Production but the general configuration like RestImpl binds to RestInterface (where the actual annotations are) resides in the DefaultConfig

I hope it's clear what i want to say.